# "closed" property abnormal returned by "window.open" in JavaScript&Opera

Tags: javascript, opera, popupwindow

I am encountering a bug-like problem in Opera when trying the get the "closed" property of a popup window.

Here is the actions I performed.

```
>>> win = open('some url in the same domain with the parent window','name','feature')
Window 
>>> win.closed //at this point, the popup window is not closed
false
>>> win.closed //at this point, the pop window is closed
false //this should be true
```

The second "false" should be "true" as I may expect.

I ran it in Chrome and Firefox, it is all right.

Any clue?

PS:
I am using Opera 11.2, Linux

Comment: Can you set up an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: @mgraph You should need to do that.

Comment: @mgraph, no, I closed it by hand. The "win" does not have "close" method at least in my Opera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine in my version of Opera, at least in the test case I put together [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DM5EV/1/).

I can close the window by hand or with the button, and the `closed` property shows the correct value.

I am using Opera version 11.61 on linux.

---

Here is the code for the test case.

```
var popup = {};

function pop() {
    popup = window.open('foo', 'foo', "menubar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=no,width=200,height=200" ); 
}    
function unpop() {
    popup.close();  
}
function check() {
    alert(({}).toString.call(popup) + ' closed: ' + popup.closed);
}

var b1 = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
var b2 = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
var b3 = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));

b1.textContent = 'open';
b2.textContent = 'close';
b3.textContent = 'check';

b1.onclick = pop;
b2.onclick = unpop;
b3.onclick = check;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade Opera. There was a known bug that broke correct .closed reporting in certain earlier versions, but it should be fixed in the most recent ones.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug in Opera. I found this resource of someone opening a bug report:
http://www.highdots.com/forums/javascript/closing-popup-window-new-opera-45642.html

Note the response:

> E Michael Brandt wrote:
>
> Thank you for confirming this, and for submitting the bug report. snip It is a known bug and a regression, it should be fixed quite soon but I can not promise that the fix will be
> in the next minor release, and I can not suggest a timeframe. Sorry
> about the inconvenience caused!